# Обработка ошибок try/except в python

Tags: python, requests, proxy, try-catch

Хочу добавить обработку ошибок для запросов, но при ошибках типа 502 или 404 не срабатывает except и дальше продолжается цикл(Одна из ссылок с ошибкой, чтоб проверить выполнение кода).
Причина в прокси, если его убрать то работает как надо, как это исправить и почему так себя ведет код?

```
list = ['http://bugmenot.com/' , 'http://bugmenot.comcom/']

def getDataSync(link, retry=5):
   
    try:
        r = requests.get(link, headers=settings.HEADERS , proxies=settings.PROXIES)
        print(r)
    except Exception as ex:
       
        if retry:
            print('[ERROR] Неудачная попытка запроса')
            time.sleep(5)
            return getDataSync(link, retry=(retry - 1))
        else:
            print('Попытки закончились')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup



def main():
    
    for link in list:
        getDataSync(link)
    print("Finished")
```

Вывод с прокси:

```
http://bugmenot.com/
409
http://bugmenot.comcom/
502
Finished
```

Без прокси:

```
[ERROR] Неудачная попытка запроса
[ERROR] Неудачная попытка запроса
[ERROR] Неудачная попытка запроса
[ERROR] Неудачная попытка запроса
[ERROR] Неудачная попытка запроса
Попытки закончились
#дальше еще куча ошибок, но это понятное поведение
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте функцию [Response.raise_for_status](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status):

```
r = requests.get(link, headers=settings.HEADERS , proxies=settings.PROXIES)
print(r)
r.raise_for_status()
```

Она выбросит исключение при статусах 4xx или 5xx

Comment: спасибо, работает. Как я понял во втором случае возвращается объект с ошибкой, а не сама ошибка, и мы запускаем ошибку с raise_for_status?

Comment: @Alexandr, пожалуйста :) В таких случаях рекомендую смотреть код https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/b0e025ade7ed30ed53ab61f542779af7e024932e/requests/models.py#L937. По коду видно, что в объекте Response проверяются значения `status_code` и выбрасывается исключение HTTPError, в которое первым параметром передается текст ошибки, а вторым сам объект Response :)